# Power Pivot VBA filter reference range of cells

Tags: vba, excel, powerpivot

I am trying to have my power pivot filter reference to a range of values in multiple cells. For example, if my filter has values A,B,C,D I want it to look into cells A1:A10 to see what values are there. If A,B exists in A1:A10 I want the filter to show only A and B (each cell only holds one value ex. A1: A, A2: B, A3: "", etc.)

With the code below I am only able to reference one value.

```
Sub SelectKey()


    Dim key As String

    key = Sheets("Sheet3").Range("R1").Value

    Sheets("data").PivotTables("PivotTable6").PivotFields("[v_cprs_dashboard_metrics].[metric_key].[metric_key]").VisibleItemsList = Array("[v_cprs_dashboard_metrics].[metric_key].&[" & key & "]")

End Sub
```

This works for regular pivot table but not powerpivot

```
With Worksheets("data").PivotTables("PivotTable6").PivotFields("metric_key")
        .ClearAllFilters
        For Each PI In .PivotItems
            PI.Visible = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Sheets("Sheet3").Range("range1"), PI.Name) > 0
        Next PI
    End With
```

Comment: try `Dim key() as String`  `key = Split(Sheets("Sheet3").Range("R1").Value,","")`

Comment: Does not work, what is that command suppose to do?

Comment: try `as Variant` ... loads the string into an array itself. if that doesn't work, see the answer i posted below

Answer (score 0):

There may be a better way to do this, but from my experience, the only way to accomplish this is to loop through the `PivotItems` in the `PivotField` and check the names against the criteria.

```
Sub SelectKey()

Dim key() As String

key = Split(Sheets("Sheet3").Range("R1").Value, ",") 'load comma separated string to array

Dim pi As PivotItem
For Each pi In Sheets("data").PivotTables("PivotTable6").PivotFields("[v_cprs_dashboard_metrics].[metric_key].[metric_key]").PivotItems

    Dim i As Integer
    For i = LBound(key) To UBound(key) 'loop through array

        If pi.Name = key(i) Then
            pi.Visible = True
            Exit For
        Else
            pi.Visible = False
        End If

    Next

Next

End Sub
```